# Doesn't the design need to be changed? Is it still being decided upon?

Tags: discussion

I don't know, but do you think this current design is a suitable one for a site on Christianity?

I don't know, perhaps, there have already been a serious consideration on this matter that I have overlooked, but there are some elements in the current design that I see as having no relation to Christianity at all.

I am especially "bothered" by that five-corner star that you click if you liked this question.

Comment: RPG.SE has been out of beta for a long time and doesn't have a site design yet - don't hold your breath, man.

Comment: @mxyzplk RPG is not out of beta. The list of beta sites are in the footer: RPG is still on it.

Comment: The pentegram has many different meanings in many different cultures. I'm pretty sure it has a spiritual meaning in some branches of Christianity.

Comment: Whichever, we're 404 days in without a design, so don't hold your breath.

Comment: update to this comment stream [rpg.se] now has a design. And it's awesome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a temporary, generic design that's given to all beta sites. The site design already has a discussion: [What should our logo and site design look like?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/436/60)

With regard to the pentagram-like favorite star, we'll get rid of it eventually.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.

Comment: The favorite button is a five-membered star in all SE designs, as far as I remember, I don't think they will deviate from that very much. Though it won't stay a pentagram, likely.

Comment: We could always use the Star of David (grins).

Comment: What about Oh Sleeper's "[broken pentagram](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=active&q=broken%20pentagram)" where the horns are ripped off?

Comment: @MadScientist. It actually isn't a pentagram: it's a [five-pointed star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-pointed_star#Comparison_with_a_pentagram).

Comment: @TRiG: Well, it *used* to be a pentagram.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman. Oh, yes, I'd actually forgotten Sketchy. My loyalty is so fickle sometimes.

Answer (score 8):

I quote Wikipedia:

> The pentagram is used as a Christian symbol for the five senses,
>   Medieval Christians believed that the "pentalpha" symbolizes the five
>   wounds of Christ. The pentagram was believed to protect against
>   demons.
>
> The pentagram figured in a heavily symbolic Arthurian romance: it
>   appears on the shield of Sir Gawain in the 14th century poem Sir
>   Gawain and the Green Knight. As the poet explains, the five points of
>   the star each have five meanings: they represent the five senses, the
>   five fingers, the five wounds of Christ, the five joys that Mary
>   had of Jesus (the Annunciation, the Nativity, the Resurrection, the
>   Ascension, and the Assumption), and the five virtues of knighthood
>   which Gawain hopes to embody: noble generosity, fellowship, purity,
>   courtesy, and compassion.

That said, the image in question is not actually a pentagram; it's the similar [five-pointed star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-pointed_star#Comparison_with_a_pentagram).

Comment: Thank you TRIG!!!!