# Why does this site still not have a logo?

Tags: discussion, logo

Why do we still not have a logo? I read some posts discussing what the logo would look like (e.g. 
[What should our logo and site design look like?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/436/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like)
).

Is the continued lack of a logo because we did not agree on it or because we should get to a certain number of users/questions/... other stuff to have the right to have a logo?

Comment: Getting there: http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/design-concept-for-christianity-se

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIRC, we're next in line.  It's just taking a while because SE only has one design guy working on these sites.

Comment: silly question: does IIRC stays for If I Recall/Remember Correctly ?

Comment: The most-recent official answer is ["Probably soon after Christmas."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7308046#7308046 "So... today?")

Comment: @JonEricson, hot off the press [even-more-recent](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/new-design-launched#comment1968_1104) answer.

Comment: @Benjol: And, [even-more-recent](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/design-concept-for-christianity-se) answer.